# Is there any way to watch Showtime shows on Samsung Gear VR?

Tags: applications, samsung-gear-vr

Last night the revival of the TV show Twin Peaks started airing on the premium cable TV network Showtime.  I'm a Comcast cable customer who's subscribed to Showtime, and I would like to watch Twin Peaks in my Samsung Gear VR headset.  So my question is, is there any way to watch Showtimes shows using Samsung Gear VR?

As you can see in [this web page](http://www.sho.com/order?s_cid=pse-default-1720&gclid=Cj0KEQjwmIrJBRCRmJ_x7KDo-9oBEiQAuUPKMpLGqHTl0WuOkmqmkgRZoAdYjaqnnlZGGkZKvY1rUiAaAqFj8P8HAQ), Showtime allows for streaming of their shows through a variety of devices and services, including through Android phones using their mobile app.  But they don't have a Gear VR app on the Oculus Store.

But is there still some way of watching their shows through Gear VR?  For instance, can it be done through a web browser (either the Samsung Internet VR Browser or the Oculus Browser)? I know that from a computer, you can stream Showtime shows via showtime.com, but when I try to visit showtime.com on my phone it redirects me to a page that links to their mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use a Plex account to play the video from the web interface you can access from Oculus Browser or Samsung Internet (it also seems to be [supported by PhoneCast](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/gear-vr/1239896026125279/)).
Then can try to use [this client](https://github.com/Dahlgren/Showtime-Plex-Client) whose Github page claims to be working with TV shows.
I have not tried it (neither Showtime), so I cannot guarantee anything, but you might want to try this solution.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, but I ultimately solved my problem another way: you can watch Showtime shows through Hulu Plus, so now I use the Hulu VR app.

Comment: That's good to know too!